# How to make appropriate action for appropriate select option(using DropKick)?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm making report page and want to show appropriate list for appropriate type of report.

I have monhly, yearly and summary reports.

Here is my select, that I want to react on:

```
  <div class="select">
        <select name="type" class="default" tabindex="7">
          <option value="monthly">Monthly report</option>
          <option value="yearly">Yearly report</option>
          <option value="summary">Summary</option>
        </select>
  </div>
```

Here is example from DropKick:

```
    $('.change').dropkick({
   change: function (value, label) {
   alert('You picked: ' + label + ':' + value);
  }
});
```

I want to use something like:

```
 $('.default').dropkick({
 change: function (value, label) {
if(value=="monthly"){
    $(".monthly").show();
  }
 else if(value="yearly"){
   $("#yearly").show();
 }
 }
});
```

but it didn't work. I have in my view hidden div, with all these selects:

```
 <div class="types">
       <div class="monthly">
          ...
        </div>
      <div class="yearly">
        ...
      </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#yearly").show();
```

should be

```
$(".yearly").show();
```

as that div uses `yearly` class, not id.

Plus you should probably hide the other div before showing one, if you only want one to be showing at once.

Just noticed one more thing

```
else if(value="yearly"){
```

should be

```
else if(value=="yearly"){
             ^ this
```

Comment: Thats misstypos in question. I just was needed to take my subdivs from parent divs. Thanks aniway, your suggestion helped me!